# How do I fully reset the global theme config in Kubuntu 23.04?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, plasma, 23.04

I have a Kubuntu 23.04 system and was trying out some global theme changes and I picked one to have a look at and it completely messed up my desktop. The only thing I see are some giant icons for running applications that span the whole screen but I cannot actually get into anything to fix the theme.

I’ve tried dropping to the command line via `CTRL-ALT-F1` and have deleting `$HOME/.local/share/plasma` but that hasn’t fixed the issue.

The theme I tried was one of the ones accessible through the settings menu so I had thought they were reasonably safe to test out. I guess there’s no *revert after 20 seconds* dialogue either… so now I’m stuck with an unusable desktop and am not sure quite what to do to get it fixed without wiping out too much of my configurations.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to just make it reset the desktop?